# Vertical Align top with each element in a new row in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a JPanel with a set of other JPanels(each containing a JLabel) in the panel. How do I setup the panel such that the inner JPanels align vertically to the top of the JPanel, and each inner panel go into a new line. Like:

```
InnerPanel 1
InnerPanel 2
InnerPanel 3


// empty space
```

I've tried setting no layout (using default layout), but the inner panels come on the same line until the line fills. Like:

```
InnerPanel 1 InnerPanel 2 InnerPanel 3
InnerPanel 4



// empty space
```

I've also tried BoxLayout and GridBagLayout, but then the inner panels space out to take up the entire vertical space of the panel like:

```
InnerPanel 1


InnerPanel 2


InnerPanel 3
```

Code:

```
public class HomeStream extends JPanel
    public HomeStream()
    {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        int counter = 0;

        // HomeStreamContent is the inner panel here containing a JLabel
        for (HomeStreamContent hsc : this.content)
        {
            this.add(hsc, getConstraints(0, counter++));
        }
    }

    public static GridBagConstraints getConstraints(int x, int y)
    {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = x;
        c.gridy = y;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 0.1;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Try using the `VerticalLayout` manager from SwingLabs [SwingX](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/1.6.2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `BoxLayout` you need to set the `maximumSize` of the panel,to the `preferredSize` as the box will cause it to stretch if you don't So for each inner panel you can do this

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override       
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }
};
```

---

[image]

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestBoxLayout {

    public TestBoxLayout() {
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                    return getPreferredSize();
                }
            };
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label");
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
            panel.add(label1);
            panel.add(label2);
            box.add(panel);

        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(box);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBoxLayout();
    }
}
```

---

Without setting the maximum

[image]

import javax.swing.Box;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestBoxLayout {

    public TestBoxLayout() {
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label");
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
            panel.add(label1);
            panel.add(label2);
            box.add(panel); 
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(box);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBoxLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)`, and after adding the four panels. add a vertical glue or rigid area. Ex:

```
panel.add(Box.createverticalGlue()); //responsive when resizing window
```

or

```
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,100))); //not responsive to window size
```

More information of using the BoxLayout:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

---

You can as well do this with GridBagLayout:

```
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gc = GridBagConstraints();
gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

gc.gridy=0;
gc.weighty = 0.1; //you might decrement this to make the panels closer to each other
panel.add(PANEL1,gc);

gc.gridy++;
panel.add(PANEL2,gc);


gc.gridy++;
panel.add(PANEL3,gc);

gc.gridy++;
gc.wieghty = 3; //you might increment this to make this last panel longer
panel.add(PANEL4,gc);
```

PS: I didn't try this code, but that's the concept.

More info on how to use GridBagLayout:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html